# Prove $|a + b|^p \leq (|a| + |b|)^p \leq (1 - \lambda)^{1 - p} |a|^p + \lambda^{1 - p} |b|^p$

Tags: inequality

Prove

$$
|a + b|^p \leq (|a| + |b|)^p \leq (1 - \lambda)^{1 - p}|a|^p + \lambda^{1 - p} |b|^p
$$

for any $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $p > 1$.

Of course the first inequality is obvious. I have tried applying the definition of convexity for $|t|^p$ but have had no luck. Also I get a feeling that Young's inequality appears somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply Jensen's inequality.

One ca express
$$|a|+|b|=\lambda\frac{|a|}{\lambda} + (1-\lambda)\frac{|b|}{1-\lambda}$$

So, as $t\mapsto |t|^p$ is convex,

$$
\Big(|a|+|b|\Big)^p=\Big(\lambda\frac{|a|}{\lambda} + (1-\lambda)\frac{|b|}{1-\lambda}\Big)^p\leq \lambda \frac{|a|^p}{\lambda^p}+(1-\lambda)\frac{|b|^p}{(1-\lambda)^p}
$$

Comment: Of course ! I can't believe I didn't see it.